# Why hitting Enter in AngularJS form's text input causes a side effect?

Tags: angularjs

[**Live Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TWCc9SiG30Jwe9N5u7pX?p=preview)

Consider the following form:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Status: </label>
    <button ng-repeat="status in statuses"
            class="btn btn-default"
            ng-model="job.status.id" btn-radio="status.id">
      {{ status.name }}
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="job.name">
  </div>
</form>
```

When focus is on the name field, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit, Status is set to "All Good" for some reason. [**Live Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TWCc9SiG30Jwe9N5u7pX?p=preview)

Why is this happening? How could I stop this side effect?

Comment: In the past I have dealt with issues like this. The problem is that everything is inside a `form` tag. Remember that hitting `Enter` on a form submits it. When you hit the `Enter` key, it messes up with Angulars internal model checking. If you replace the `form` tag with a `div` the problem goes away. Let me look at it more closely to see if I can find a better solution.

Comment: So in this particular case, what is happenning is that when you hit `Enter`, the `job.status.id` model is being reset to a default value of `1` after form submission. You can see this happens if you replace `id` for `_id` in the `$scope.job` model. After you hit enter, a new attribute will be appended: `id`. As to how to prevent the form submission from trampling your model I am still looking at some of my older code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the ngForm docs:

> This is because of the following form submission rules in the HTML
>   specification:
>
> If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field
>   triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
>
> if a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or input[type=submit] 
>   then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
>
> if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons
>   or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields
>   will trigger the click handler on the first button or
>   input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing
>   form (ngSubmit)

Default type for the `button` element is "submit" (`<button></button> === <button type="submit"></button>`). Hence, when you hit enter, the first button is submitted.

To remedy, just put `type="button"` on your buttons.

```
<button 
  ng-repeat="status in statuses"
  class="btn btn-default"
  ng-model="job.status.id" 
  btn-radio="status.id"
  type="button"
>
  {{ status.name }}
</button>
```

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed this.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. Fixed my problems! But don't you think this shouldn't be like this. I mean default type for button is submit.